# using a case statement inside a string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to put a case statement in a string. How can this be achieved?

```
select DATEDIFF(MM, select CASE FA.new_ownertype
        WHEN 8 then FA.new_vlenrollmentstartdate
        ELSE FA.new_contractstartdate from BingMapsPlatform_Stagging.dbo.FilteredAccount as FA
        END, GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 4):

```
select DATEDIFF(MM,
    CASE FA.new_ownertype
    WHEN 8 then FA.new_vlenrollmentstartdate
    ELSE FA.new_contractstartdate
    END, GETDATE())
from BingMapsPlatform_Stagging.dbo.FilteredAccount as FA
```